# Vue.js 2.0 (Vuetify) align v-switch and v-button on the right of an element

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I can't manage to align vuetify elements v-switch and v-btn on the same line of a v-card-subtitle.

I'm trying to have within a `<v-card-subtitle/>` (on the same line) the following elements :
`<v-switch v-model="switch" label="Finished" color="info" hide-details></v-switch>`
and
`Reload <v-btn icon color="primary"><v-icon>mdi-reload></v-icon></v-btn>`

And those two elements must be placed on the right of a `<v-card-subtitle/>`

My code so far is the following :

```
<v-card>
    <v-card-title>
        ...
    </v-card-title>
    <v-card-subtitle>
        <v-row>
            <v-col class="text-left">
                <v-switch v-model="ex11"
                    label="Finished" color="info"
                    hide-details>
                </v-switch>

                Reload
                <v-btn icon color="primary">
                    <v-icon>mdi-reload
                    </v-icon>
                </v-btn>

            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-card-subtitle>
</v-card>
```

and leads to the attached image.  [image]

I'd like the elements to be aligned on the right of the card-subtitle if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put the elements in a grid column, `<v-col>` which is going to align them vertically by default.  You can simply remove the column element and they'll be aligned horizontally as children of `<v-row>`. To align them neatly on the right-hand side of the card, you can use flex based [`<v-row>` props](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-row/#props) like `align="center" justify="end"`.

```html
<v-card-subtitle>
  <v-row align="center" justify="end">
    <v-switch
      class="ma-0 pa-0"
      v-model="ex11"
      label="Finished"
      color="info"
      hide-details
    >
    </v-switch>

    Reload
    <v-btn icon color="primary">
      <v-icon>mdi-reload </v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </v-row>
</v-card-subtitle>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/jOKyRXz) example.

Comment: thks works as expected now !